# Hide attributes in Visio

Tags: entity-relationship, visio

I have an ER diagram in Visio. How can I hide the attributes of all entities and show only the entities in the diagram. My visio version is 2010.

Answer (score 0):

Try Database -> Display Options -> Table.
This dialog allows you to control the content to be shown.

Note that this question appears to be unrelated to stackoverflow ("not a programming question")

Comment: Where can I find the database option?

Comment: It's on the "Database" tab. Button "Display Options" opens the dialog "Display Options", where you can set what to show. Table display options are on tab "Table".